Не отображается 3D модель загруженная из файла obj
Пытаюсь загрузить 3D модель из файла формата obj. qt ее вроде как загружает, судя по изменению статусу sceneLoader но не отображает на сцене.
this->camera = this->view.camera();
this->mpl = new MyPointLight(parent);

this->objectEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(parent);
this->sceneLoader = new Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader(objectEntity);
this->planeMaterials = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(objectEntity);
this->objectTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(objectEntity);

this->camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(
    60.0f,
    (float)view.width()/(float)view.height(),
    0.1f,
    1000.0f
    );
this->camera->setPosition(QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0, 40.0));
this->camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
this->view.setRootEntity(parent);

this->sceneLoader->setSource(QUrl("полный путь к файлу/cube.obj"));

this->planeMaterials->setDiffuse(QColor(0, 0, 0));
this->objectTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(0.0,0.0,0.0));
this->objectTransform->setScale(0.1f);

this->objectEntity->addComponent(sceneLoader);
this->objectEntity->addComponent(planeMaterials);
this->objectEntity->addComponent(objectTransform);

QObject::connect(sceneLoader, &Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::statusChanged, [](Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::Status status) {
    switch (status) {
    case  Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::None:
        qDebug() << "Статус: None (загрузчик не активен)";
        break;
    case  Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::Loading:
        qDebug() << "Статус: Loading (загрузка в процессе)";
        break;
    case  Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::Ready:
        qDebug() << "Статус: Ready (загрузка завершена успешно)";
        break;
    case  Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::Error:
        qDebug() << "Статус: Error (ошибка при загрузке)";
        break;
    }
});

Пробовал использовать как собственноручно созданный файл, так и загруженный из интернета. Результат одинаков.
Аналогичная ситуация при попытке загружать модель через Mesh

view.show(); ?
